# SQL order by highest value of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with some doubles, they store precentages. so let's say the columns are `pc_1` and `pc_2`.

What I want is to order by whichever of these two columns has the highest amount descending, and then by the other column, again descending.

So if our data is as follows:

```
id  pc_1  pc_2 
 1  12.5  11.0
 2  10.0  13.2
 3  13.2  9.0
```

```sql
select * from mytable order by <something>
```

Would give:

```
 2  10.0  13.2
 3  13.2  9.0
 1  12.5  11.0
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        GREATEST(pc_1, pc_2) DESC, LEAST(pc_1, pc_2) DESC
```

Comment: Huh, not sure I missed greatest and least all these years. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `GREATEST` and `LEAST` are not standard SQL.

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from mytable
order by 
case when pc_1 > pc_2 then pc_1 else pc_2 end desc,
case when pc_1 > pc_2 then pc_2 else pc_1 end desc
```